# SQL help solving dynamic column categorisation

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, grouping, pivot-table

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have this table of WBS structure:

```
level   id   parentid   name
================================
1       1    -1         WBS 1      -> root
2       2    1          WBS 1.1    -> child of WBS 1
2       3    1          WBS 1.2    -> child of WBS 1
3       4    2          WBS 1.1.1  -> child of WBS 1.1
3       5    2          WBS 1.1.2  -> child of WBS 1.1
3       6    3          WBS 1.2.1  -> child of WBS 1.2
```

and I need to categorize the ids into this:

```
level1   level2   level3   parentid   name
==============================================
1        null     null     -1         WBS 1
null     2        null     1          WBS 1.1
null     3        null     1          WBS 1.2
null     null     4        2          WBS 1.1.1
null     null     5        2          WBS 1.1.2
null     null     6        3          WBS 1.2.1
```

And the real problem is that the level is dynamic, meaning that the table can have more or less than 3 levels

My question is, is this doable? Maybe via pivot or some other means?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, just google "dynamic pivot sql".

Comment: Then, after you've Googled, have a go and if you don't succeed, post what you're tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    declare @ColumnName VARCHAR(max)
    declare @DynamicPivotQuery varchar(max)

--Get  values of the PIVOT Column    
    SET @ColumnName = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',[' + Cast( c.[level] as nvarchar(10))+']'
                FROM Pivot_Example c
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
    set @DynamicPivotQuery = 'SELECT  ' + @ColumnName + ', parentid, [name]  from <br/>(
                    select parentid
                        ,  [name]
                        , id 
                        , [level]
                    from Pivot_Example
               ) x
                pivot 
                (
                     min(ID)
                    for [level] in (' + @ColumnName + ')
                ) p order by parentid'

 --Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
    execute(@DynamicPivotQuery)
```

http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: If you add a little explanation to your answer it would be even better :)

Comment: For Static pivot , we require the column name in the IN section of the query .

Comment: But for dynamic we need to create that and later it need to be append with the original query .

Comment: So @ColumnName  variable is use to get the distinct columns on which pivot is to be performed .

Comment: Again @DynamicPivotQuery variable is use to concat column with pivot query .At last it need to be executed